# Java/AWT/Swing: how to distinguish the pressed enter or return key

Tags: java, swing, macos, keyboard, awt

It looks like native applications behave differently if the user presses the Return key (right to the characters) or the Enter key (number key pad) - one time a new line character is inserted, the other time the default button is activated.

How I can distinguish both key presses from Java/AWT/Swing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
keyEvent.getKeyLocation() == KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this is not handled by KeyStroke, so one can't assign different actions for the Enter or Return key. :(

Comment: Note: This also only works for keyPressed events, not keyTyped events.