# Using javaFx, how to distinguish between return-key and enter-key on the numpad?

Tags: javafx, keyboard, numpad

Using javaFx, how to distinguish between return-key and enter-key on the numpad?

This is a near duplicate of [Java/AWT/Swing: how to distinguish the pressed enter or return key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3270715/4142984) , but for javaFX.

Unfortunately, in javaFX, there is no `KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD`.

Comment: Have you tried `KeyCode#isKeypadKey`?

Comment: I tested `KeyCode#isKeypadKey,` and it did not work for `Enter`. It worked for the numbers.

Comment: @SedJ601 the documentation says otherwise, but it does not work for numpad-enter nor for any other key on the numpad except for the digits, and even for those only when numlock is active.

Answer (score 1):

`String` properties of `KeyEvent` might contain some useful information.

The `event.getText()` resulted in different values for *return* and *numpad* enter keys in my tests (*openjfx 21.0.2*).

```java
import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Enters extends Application {

    private static final int RETURN_KEY_CODE = 13;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Label label = new Label("Press the keys");
        label.setPadding(new Insets(50));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(label));

        stage.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> {
            if (e.getCode() != KeyCode.ENTER) {
                return;
            }
            int textCh = (e.getText().length() > 0) ? e.getText().charAt(0) : -1;
            int ch = (e.getCharacter().length() > 0) ? e.getCharacter().charAt(0) : -1;
            boolean keypadEnter = (textCh != RETURN_KEY_CODE);
            
            System.out.println(String.format(
                    "%sENTER\tTextCode:%s CharCode:%s",
                    (keypadEnter ? "NUMPAD " : ""), textCh, ch));
        });
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
ENTER   TextCode:13 CharCode:0
ENTER   TextCode:13 CharCode:0
NUMPAD ENTER    TextCode:-1 CharCode:0
ENTER   TextCode:13 CharCode:0
NUMPAD ENTER    TextCode:-1 CharCode:0
```

There is no guarantee that this is platform independent or that field population won't change in the future versions.

Comment: Maybe it's just bad luck on my system, but System.out.println("Text=" + e.getText()); is empty, where "e"  comes from scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.ANY, e ->

Comment: @GyroGearloose [the text from the key event] is "for key pressed and key released events. For key typed events, text is always the empty string."  So, when you are filtering any key event, for some events you would expect an empty string (though for others it would be expected to be populated).  But I guess you tested all types and even for the types where you expected a value you didn't receive one on your system, which would be a bug for those event types, I would think.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Printing "e.getText()" appears empty in my system too because `\r` is a *whitespace*. To check whether both keys produce the same values: `System.out.println("Texts=" + e.getText().chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()) + e.getCharacter().chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));`